# Efficiency of thermodynamic cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I am trying to calculate the thermal efficiency for a cycle which includes a process, where ideal gas gives out heat and its volume decreases. Does this mean, that work is done to the gas? So when I calculate the efficiency, is it simply the ratio of work done by the gas and the heat brought to the gas? Or should I count the work done to the gas as well to the 'taken energy' when I calculate the efficiency?

Cycle goes A -> B -> C -> A

B -> C is isothermal process.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you could include a $p,V$ diagram of your process.

Comment: What process B-C? Adiabatic? Isothermal? Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t shown details of the process, but for any heat engine cycle when you calculate the cycle efficiency you use the net work done by the gas divided by the heat brought in. The net work done is the heat in minus the heat out.

$$eff=\frac{W_{net}}{Q_{in}}=\frac{Q_{in}-Q_{out}}{Q_{in}}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: If volume of the gas decreases (B -> C), is the negative work taken into account? If so, is it work done by the gas or done to the gas? Does it affect the efficiency?

Comment: ??you said the process is from B to C. That’s an increase in volume and work is done by the gas. If the process is from C to be the volume decreases and work is done on the gas Which is it?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad! I meant C -> A, where volume decreases.

Comment: Ok. For process C to A work is done on the gas. It has to be subtracted from the work done by the gas in process B to C to get the net work done. The net work is then the area enclosed by the cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Work done between two states $1$ and $2$ is defined as:

$$W_{1 \to 2}=\int_{V_1}^{V_2}p(V)\text{d}V$$

In your case the **net work** is represented by the area  arched in amber, minus the area arched in amber and green:

[image: Work]